# Complete newbie CSS question about navigation bars and content boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to create a page with a horizontal navigation bar spanning the top of the page and a box with content underneath. The navigation bar is not a big problem: there are plenty of tutorials to explain how to use CSS to style a simple HTML list into a navigation bar. But I don't know how to handle the content box: I want the user's selection (i.e., selecting from the options on the navigation bar) to determine which content shows up in the box.

Here's the HTML. You can see that I've taken a friend's preexisting HTML and simplified it:

> - http://jsfiddle.net/4FgFT/

Currently it just displays three boxes. I'd like it to display one box, with its content determined by which option the user selects from the navigation bar. I hope this is clear. Thanks.

Comment: You seem to be using XHTML and not HTML. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the `idTabs` plugin, you have one more step to go.

For your three `mainbox` divs, they each need an ID matching up to your tab names (as defined in the `ul`).

So the first div should have `id="optiona"`, the second should have `id="optionb"`, etc.

Based on this page: http://www.sunsean.com/idTabs/, and tested myself. :)

**Some notes**: `display: block` is not necessary for your divs. They are block-level by default.

`white-space: nowrap` means that text inside the element will never wrap to the next line, and continue on until you put in a break yourself.

You are using XHTML (based on the `DOCTYPE` and additional cruft in the `<html>` tag). Since you said you took your friend's stuff and copied it, you probably don't intend to. I suggest `<!DOCTYPE html>` and `<html>` to indicate HTML5 compatibility instead of locking yourself into XHTML.

Answer (score 2):

> - **DEMO:** http://aseptik.net/demo/complete-newbie-css-question-about-navigation-bars-and-content-boxes/

```
$(function() {
    $('#topmenu1 li a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var tabContent = this.hash;
        $(tabContent).show().siblings('.mainbox').hide()
    });
});
```

html

```
<ul><li><a href="#optiona">Option A</a></li></ul>

    <div id="optiona" class="mainbox">
    <h2>Option A</h2>
    <p>You've selected Option A. Here is a list.</p>
        <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

---

> - **[Pure CSS solution](http://www.cssplay.co.uk)** > http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/slide_show

Comment: Do you know of any material on that website that addresses this problem? I see lots of material on navigation bars, but nothing that addresses how to make the content depend on the user's selection. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like this is Javascript. I guess I'll look around for a tutorial on the commands you're using.

Comment: yes, is not just javascript, also your html structure should be corrected as i showed in the demo. also in your original code you have missing </a> tags. etc etc...

Comment: if my answer solved your problem pls tick the check simbol on top right. thank's.

Comment: Use `fadeOut()` and `fadeIn() to make it look nicer.